# .htaccess scope of RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm creating an .htaccess file for my need in my server:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   #Enable the Rewrite Engine
   RewriteEngine On

   #Rewrite the base to / if this is not local host
   RewriteBase /

   #Set the base in case of local development
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)localhost(.*)$
   RewriteBase /~asafnevo/api

   #Redirect every request to the index.php
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC]

   # Prevent direct access to access to the index.php
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
   RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ - [F]


</IfModule>
```

I added the:

```
   #Set the base in case of local development
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)localhost(.*)$
   RewriteBase /~asafnevo/api
```

in order to have different base in my localhost development environment, but my question is when does the RewriteCond ends?

I tried to do

```
   RewriteBase /~asafnevo/api [L]
```

but I receive an 500 error.

Can someone please expend of scopes in matters of RewriteCond ?

Comment: look at the server error log for details about the 500.

Comment: @anubhava can you please expend on how it should be done?

Comment: Looks like you've accepted an answer, glad that answer worked out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `RewriteBase` incorrectly. You can't use the `[L]` flag because it's not a **RewriteRule**, hence the 500 error you are getting. Also you can only have **1** `RewriteBase` in your rules. If the file has multiple Bases, it will use the last one. So it will start to cause problems if you actually tried to use this in production with multiple `RewriteBase`'s.

> The RewriteBase directive specifies the URL prefix to be used for
>   per-directory (htaccess) RewriteRule directives that substitute a
>   relative path.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

And RewriteCond is only used for Rules.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

You will just have to edit your .htaccess if you're on a local box or keep 2 copies and just rename it when you need it for locally.

Answer (score 4):

A `RewriteCond` is only evaluated for the next `RewriteRule` directive that is encountered. Mod_rewrite will evaluate the first argument of `RewriteRule` first, then it will evaluate all `RewriteCond` it encountered after the last time it encountered a `RewriteRule` and if all evaluates to true, it will perform the requested rewrite.

Consider the following example:

```
RewriteCond . . #1
RewriteCond . . #2
RewriteRule . . #3

RewriteCond . . #4
RewriteRule . . #5
```

If the first argument of #3 matches, it will evaluate conditions #1 and #2, then rewrite to the second argument of #3. If the first argument of #5 matches, it will evaluate #4, then rewrite to the second argument of #5.